# wordpress pmpro plugin register field error check

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using pmpro and an api to register members in my site and in a third party site. My problem is I have site A(my site) and site B(store members here using api). I first register to site A -> (check_1) check if fields are error free -> if error free, proceed to site B -> (check_2) site B checks if fields inputted are acceptable then saves fields to site B if it is -> Site A saves fields if site B save succeeds.

Everything is working well except I need to know how to execute a code after check_1. Like if $errors = 0 execute code if not redirect to register page something like that but I was not able to figure out how pmpro does the error checking.

Appreciate all the answers I can get. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oops posted a comment instead of an answer.

Solved it using this:

add_action('pmpro_checkout_before_processing', 'check_stuff');